# How does this affine cipher work?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, affine-cipher

I have a question about how I need to solve the following:

A sentence has been changed to ASCII and then encrypted with the formula $E(x) = ax + b \bmod 256256$. All I know is that the first 4 letters are: `W I S K`

This is the encrypted message:

```
 064066 158368 092525 143358 099354 141643 110102 051667 024006 190286 133343
```

How do I go about solving this? I first tried to program a brute force but I actually want to understand how to solve it. I tried working with the extended euclidean algorithm as well, but didn't get far.

Answer (score 6):

`W` is 87 in ASCII, so
$$
87a+b\equiv064066\pmod{256256}.
$$

`I` is 73 in ASCII, so
$$
73a+b\equiv158368\pmod{256256}.
$$

Subtracting, you get
$$
14a\equiv-94302\equiv161954\pmod{256256}.
$$

Unfortunately 14 is not coprime to 256256, so you'll need to use other letters to figure this out. Once you get an equation of the form
$$
ma\equiv n\pmod{256256}
$$
you can solve for $a\pmod{256256}$ and then substitute to find $b\pmod{256256}.$

(In fact, you already have enough to solve with trial and error, but it's nicer to avoid that.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got a few questions though.

What exactly do you mean by, substitute?

Assuming the first seven letters are: `W I S K U N D E`, can I do the following?


`E` is 73 in ASCII and `N` is 78 in ASCII.

Therefore having:
$$
78a+b\equiv141643\pmod{256256}.
$$
and
$$
73a+b\equiv092525\pmod{256256}.
$$
Subtracting them
$$
5a+b\equiv49118\pmod{256256}.
$$

I believe 5 is coprime to 256256. If I follow your equation:
$$
5a\equiv49118\pmod{256256}.
$$

How exactly do I calculate b? Sorry if the questions seem obvious, having a hard time comprehending.

Comment: @Lada: $78a+b-(73a+b)=5a$, not $5a+b.$ You then get $a$ from the extended Euclidean algorithm, and to get $b$ you compute, say, $092525-73a$.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

`I` in ASCII is 73 and `D`in ASCII is 68.

Substracting them I get the formula:
$$
5a\equiv48266\pmod{256256}.
$$
Using the extended Euclidean algorithm I find that a 214658 is.  I also calculate that b:
$$
110102 - 68 * 214658\equiv119950\pmod{256256}.
$$

Whenever I insert these values ( a and b ) in the original formula:
$$
E(x)=ax+bmod256256
$$
I only get the correct values for I and D. What am I doing wrong this time? I can not find a coprime in 256256 with just the letters `W I S K` by the way, or did I forget something?

Comment: @Lada Where does D come from? I thought you only had WISK.

Comment: I did indeed only have WISK, but I highly suspect the first 8 letters are WISKUNDE, since that means math in dutch. Besides with just WISK I can't find a coprime with 256256.

Comment: None of the ${4\choose2}=6$ possibilities work? How odd. I guess you could just compute each of the 14 possibilities my analysis gives mod 18304.

Comment: 87-73 = 14 (not coprime to 256256)
87-83 = 4 (not coprime to 256256)
87-75 = 12 (not coprime to 256256)
75-73 = 2 (not coprime to 256256)
83-75 = 8 (not coprime to 256256)
83-73 = 10 (not coprime to 256256)

"18304" You mean that a = 18304 ?

Comment: @Lada: A simple brute force check shows that $14 a \equiv 161954 \pmod{256256}$ has no solutions. Thus, either your known plaintext (or ciphertext) or your description of the ciphering method is incorrect. (Also, while asking how to solve a particular *type* of cipher is OK, [asking to have a particular piece of ciphertext decoded is considered off-topic here.](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/q/100) Thus, even though it may not help you with this specific ciphertext, Charles's answer really does cover the entire *on-topic* part of your question.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry if it went off-topic, that wasn't my intention. I genuily don't know how to solve an equation of this type. I triple checked and my description of the ciphering method is correct...

Comment: The message begins with:
`W I S K`
Further,  you know that ASCI code is encrypted using an encryption function of the form $$E (x) = ax + b$$
Calculations were done with$$mod 256256$$ 

`064066 158368 092525 143358 099354 141643 110102 051667 024006 190286 133343`

This is it.

Answer (score 1):

`W` = 87; `I` = 73; `S` = 83; `K` = 75

This yields the following system of equations:

$\begin{cases}
87a+b \equiv 64066 \pmod {256256}\\
73a+b \equiv 158368 \pmod {256256}\\
83a+b \equiv 92525 \pmod {256256}\\
75a+b \equiv 143358 \pmod {256256}
\end{cases}$

The following proposition is useful.

**Proposition** If $x \equiv y \pmod {n}$ then $x \equiv y \pmod {n/d}$ for any divisor $d$ of $n$.

You can therefore solve the above system modulo the factors of $256256 = 2^8 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$.

For example, modulo $7$, we obtain:

$\begin{cases}
3a+b \equiv 2\pmod {7}\\
3a+b \equiv 0 \pmod {7}\\
6a+b \equiv 6 \pmod {7}\\
5a+b \equiv 5 \pmod {7}
\end{cases}$

The two first equations (modulo $7$) are impossible.  This means that $a$ and $b$ cannot be recovered modulo $7$.

Let us now look modulo $11$:

$\begin{cases}
10a+b \equiv 2\pmod {11}\\
7a+b \equiv 1 \pmod {11}\\
6a+b \equiv 4 \pmod {11}\\
9a+b \equiv 6 \pmod {11}
\end{cases}$

The two first equations yield $a\equiv 4 \pmod {11}$ and $b\equiv 6 \pmod {11}$.  However, these solutions are incompatible with the two last equations.

*I suspect that there are some errors in the problem.  Can you check the values of the ciphertext.  Or I made mistakes in the calculation...*;)

Comment: I will come with an answer tomorrow, interesting way of approaching the problem by the way, never thought of it.

Comment: Since decryption is given by $E^{-1}(y) = (y-b)\cdot a^{-1} \bmod 256256$, the value of $a$ defining encryption should be relatively prime to $256256$; i.e., $\gcd(a,256256) = 1$.  You should check that with your teacher.

Comment: I concur -- the problem, as written, is not solvable.

Comment: @Charles @user94293 Well, this might be the issue: According to my teacher `W I` are encrypted to $064066$ and `S K` to $158368$

Comment: @Lada: Assuming that ASCII codes are concatenated (i.e., $x = 087073$ for `WI` and $x=083057$ for `SK`), this yields $a=249951$ and $b=158979$.  The problem is that this $a$ cannot be inverted modulo $256256$: $\gcd(249951,256256) = 13$.

Comment: @Charles and @user94293 You were correct, it was incorrect. I got a new one but I can't seem to solve it again...

$$E(x)=ax+b mod 215475$$

The first 4 letters are  `W i s k` and the encrypted text is:
`091238  057542  070713  195800  138772  029721  035480`

Each group of 6 numbers resembles 2 letters.

What I did was:
`W i` in ASCII is 087105 and `s k` is 115107

$$
115107a+b\equiv057542\pmod{215475}.
$$


$$
087105a+b\equiv091238\pmod{215475}.
$$


Subtracting I get:
$$
28002a\equiv181779\pmod{215475}.
$$

$28002$ is not coprime to $215475$ .. What's the issue?

Comment: @Lada:  Encryption should be injective: each ciphertext has then a unique corresponding plaintext.  For the affine cipher, this is guaranteed if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$.  In your case, $\gcd(28002,215475) = 39$ and so the plaintext message cannot be fully recovered.  You could suggest your teacher to use a prime modulus, for example, $n = 255259$.

Comment: @user94293 Correct, but is there any other way I could get $gcd(a,n)=1$ with my numbers? Did I even do it the correct way? I also know that $a$ and $b$ are primes. Are you telling me this problem is also not solvable?

Comment: @Lada: Yes, the new problem is not solvable.